# How to connect Android Emulator as external USB Device to Windows 10?

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, emulation, android-virtual-device

I used android studio to create AVD of Pixel 3A running Android 11 (API 30). How can I connect/emulate this AVD to host Windows 10 as an external device ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you already created you AVD, you just have to hit the green play button. I advise you to read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you provide more details to your question body. What exactly are you trying to do - to use the virtual device you just use the emulator interface you don't have to connect it to a usb like a real device. Do you want to simulate what happens when a device is plugged in and connected to a windows pc?

Comment: Yes, I want to connect the virtual device as a real device to the host system.